# Compress backup directory using shell script

Tags: centos

I am Writing a shell script for data backup.My script Backup data Successfully.But Directory not compressed.I can't find what was wrong my shell script

```
MONGO_DATABASE="database"
APP_NAME="appname"
MONGO_HOST="localhost"
MONGO_PORT="port"
MONGO_USER=""
MONGO_PASS=""
TIMESTAMP=`date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S"`
MONGODUMP_PATH="mongopath"
BACKUPS_DIR="backup path"
BACKUP_NAME="$APP_NAME-$TIMESTAMP"
# mongo admin --eval "printjson(db.fsyncLock())"
$MONGODUMP_PATH --host $MONGO_HOST  -d $MONGO_DATABASE --port $MONGO_PORT 
#$MONGODUMP_PATH -d $MONGO_DATABASE
# mongo admin --eval "printjson(db.fsyncUnlock())"

mkdir -p $BACKUPS_DIR
#tar -cvf filename.tar files/directories
mv dump $BACKUP_NAME* $BACKUPS_DIR
tar -cvz -f $BACKUP_NAME.tar.gz $BACKUP_NAME
find $BACKUP_NAME -type d -ctime +10 | xargs rm -rf
#rm -rf $BACKUP_NAME
```

Comment: Probably a typo. You're moving `$BACKUP_NAME*` to `BACKUPS_DIR` but then you're archiving `$BACKUP_NAME` rather than `$BACKUPS_DIR/$BACKUP_NAME*` (or something similar). You should also strongly considering adding double-quotes to all of your variable expansions.  This is particularly important when you, as here, use `BACKUPS_DIR="backup path"` (variable contains spaces).

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with these two lines:

```
mv dump $BACKUP_NAME* $BACKUPS_DIR
tar -cvz -f $BACKUP_NAME.tar.gz $BACKUP_NAME
```

Notice that you're moving `dump` and `$BACKUP_NAME*` away from the current directory with the `mv` on the first line, and then try to add `$BACKUP_NAME*` from the current directory to an archive on the second.

My feeling is that you instead might want to use

```
mv dump "$BACKUP_NAME"* "$BACKUPS_DIR"
tar -cvz -f "$BACKUP_NAME.tar.gz" "$BACKUPS_DIR"
```

This creates a `tar` archive of the `$BACKUPS_DIR` directory. However, I'm not sure why you have `$BACKUP_NAME*` on the first line as I can't see anything creating files with this name... (but I might be missing something).

Also, do consider quoting your variable expansions as I did above, throughout your script. This is especially important if you use names of files or directories that contain spaces.